# About the Cuspidal representations of general linear group in the book "Lie Groups" by Daniel Bump

Tags: representation-theory, finite-fields

I was trying to understand the proof (**On Page 403, Proposition 49.2 in the book "Lie Groups" by Daniel Bump**) that any irreducible representation of G = GL(n,F), where F is a finite field, is either cuspidal or a constituent of a principal series representation induced from a parabolic subgroup of G.

The proof is by induction, but in the last part of the proof (on page 404), it is said that there exists a homomorphism from a module over Levi subgroup and then the concept of Frobenius reciprocity is used. Can anyone explain that part to me?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of cuspidal representation he is using here? I ask because many places take "not a constituent of a principal series representation induced from a parabolic subgroup of G" to essentially be the definition of cuspidal.

Comment: it is a representation which has no fixed vector under the action of unipotent radical of any maximal parabolic subgroup